# php syntax naming, I would like to see if it is correct

Tags: php, syntax

Hey I've been reviewing over w3schools and I just want to check if my naming of syntax is right

if someone can check it or help me out

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['name2'])) {
    $num=$_POST['name'];
    $num2=$_POST['name2'];
    echo  $num . ' multiplyed by '. $num2 . ' = '.$num*$num2;
}

else{
    echo '';
}


?>
```

the `if` is a condition statement?

`isset` is function

`$_POST[name]` is inside the parameter and it is a global variable (question what exactly is the definition of a global variable)

`$num` and `$num2` are variables

`name` and `name2` are marks from the HTML name, but what is the correct definition of `name` and `name2`

Comment: `name` and `name2` are *keys* of an [*array*](http://ie1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (namely the [*superglobal*](http://ie1.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) `$_POST`).

Comment: Incidentally, if you’re just learning PHP, I’d recommend [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) over W3 Schools.

Comment: it does run, i check code academy, I just want to know the proper names. I can code it, just dont know if the name of the syntax are correct

Comment: W3Schools is a terrible source to learn anything, really. See: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Please don't use W3 Schools or Codeacademy. If you want to do it correctly, then [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. - `if` in PHP it is called a construct. But many would argue it okay to call a conditional statement. A conditional statement is really the statement inside the if block. As you can see we actully have multiple statements.

```
if(condition) { // <- This is a if statement.
    statement // the statement is conditional.
```

yes - `isset` is a native php function

yes - `$num and $num2` are variables. (if you do not know all types a variable can be in PHP, now would be a great time to learn.)

Lastly *"name and name2 are marks from the HTML name, but what is the correct definition of name and name2"* no -  are called keys, array index or subscript. These provide a way to define which specific index in a array we are using.

$_POST is a native superglobal variable of the type array. A superglobal is accessable from all scopes. If you have not yet encountered what scopes are, no worries, you will as soon.